# Chi-square distribution and uniform distribution

Tags: statistics

I have been stuck with this problem for a long time I hope you can help me.

random variable $X$ has chi-square distribution with 2 degrees of freedom

random variable $Y=e^{-X/2}$

prove that random variable $Y$ has a uniform distribution  in the interval $(0,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chi-squared distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom is just the exponential with density function $\frac{1}{2}e^{-x/2}$ for $x\gt 0$, and $0$ elsewhere. In particular, $\Pr(X\ge x)=e^{-x/2}$ for $x\gt 0$.

We first find the cdf $F_Y(y)$ of $Y$. Clearly $\Pr(Y\le y)=0$ if $y\le 0$, and $\Pr(Y\le y)=1$ if $y\ge 1$. For $0\lt y\lt 1$ we have
$$\small F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(e^{-X/2}\le y)=\Pr\left(\frac{-X}{2}\le \ln y\right)=\Pr(X\ge -2\ln y)=e^{(2\ln y)/2}=y.$$
To find the density function $f_Y(y)$ of $Y$, differentiate $F_Y$. We get $f_Y(y)=1$ for $0\lt y\lt 1$.

Comment: thanks a lot andre, I am a beginner in statistics so it took me a while to understand your answer but that was really helpful! thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. Alternately I could have used the method of transformations. It is shorter, but I have found students often understand going through the cumulative distribution function better. What I wrote is a little densely written, sorry. The result we got is related to something important in simulations.

Comment: What you wrote is really helpful thanks